# a question about continuous differentiable function

Tags: calculus

Given f is a continuous differentiable funtion, 
what is the sufficient condition for 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \int_{-n}^{x}f'(s)ds\rightarrow f(x) ?$$

the hint from the instructor is that thinking about the behavior of f, f' when x approaches to negative infinity. any idea to get started with it? Got stuck for so long....got no clue...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What will guarantee that $f(x)-f(-n)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: when f(-n) goes to 0 as n goes to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

If $f'$ is a continuous function, the fundamental theorem of calculus might help.
This theorem states that, if $f'$ is a continuous function, then
$$
\int_a^b f'(x)dx = f(b)-f(a)
$$
try using it to get some conclusions. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The integral is evaluated to be: $f(x)-f(-n)$.

And this result tends to $f(x)$ if $f(-n)$ tends to zero, meaning that $f(x)$ should go to zero as $x$ goes to negative infinity.